# Allow/Block windows process in a winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, system.diagnostics

I've made a winform application that allows you to kill processes and gives a notification for a new process that starts. I need to add functionality to allow/block i.e blacklist/whitelist a process, so that it won't run while my application is running.

Any suggestions?

Comment: More explanation please...

Comment: Please do some research yourself before asking it here. Or tell us what you have done or tried to accomplish your goals

Comment: Guys I searched for methods but can't find any good ones to be used. Just asking if you got something in mind!

Comment: @user966614 Your question is *still* unclear... What exactly do you mean by "blacklist/whitelist a process, so that it won't run while my application is running."

Comment: Allow/Block I meant. Like if I allow the process it'll run when ever I start it. Blocking would add it to the block list and it will not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - Here is a ***basic*** example of how to work with processes.
This is based on the assumption that you have a list of process names named `blackList` and you want to kill any process which is on this list:

```
List<string> blackList = new List<string>();

// TODO: Populate the list with "black listed" processes

// Kill any process which is in the blacklist
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (blackList.Any(x => x.ToLowerInvariant().Equals(process.ProcessName.ToLowerInvariant())))
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```

This should help get you started in the right direction...